# SELECT no of columns dynamically from DUAL

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have a requirement like below :

I have to show 10 columns every time.

Suppose I am selecting from a table `tab` which has 7 columns, I have to add 3 extra columns like below:

```
select * from tab,(select 'dummy' d1 , 'dummy' d2 , 'dummy' d3 from dual);
```

If the no of columns in the table increases to 8 then:

```
select * from tab,(select 'dummy' d1 , 'dummy' d2  from dual);
```

Is there any way to achieve this in **Oracle 11g** **without using PL/SQL?**

Comment: You can retrieve number of columns in your table using [INFORMATION_SCHEMA](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_schema) and dynamically add needed length of dummy columns to your SQL statement

Comment: How to dynamically add needed length of dummy columns without using PL/SQL ?

Comment: You do not need PLSql to access information schema, simple SQL would do. At the end of the day, you have to execute SQL to get your final result?

Comment: I know how to retrieve data from information schema and count how many rows are there in the table: `select count(colum_id) from sys.all_tab_cols where table_name ='tab';` But I am stuck with the second part, **dynamically add the needed length of dummy columns**

Comment: Second part has nothing to do with SQL - do it in your code to dynamically generate SQL query, e.g. Java, Python, etc.

Comment: Wow! Great! I cannot use PL/SQL but I can use Java Python. Thanks.

Comment: Totally lost.  The `*` will select all the columns in the table.  So you don't need to manually add any more.

Comment: What datatype are your columns?

Comment: @wolφi varchar2, all of them.

Comment: Now you have to tell us why you are required to fill up to 10 columns...

Answer (score 0):

I think this cannot be done.

I'd solve it with a view. You can generate/update the view automatically, but only using PL/SQL which violates your requirement:

```
DECLARE
  a CONSTANT VARCHAR2(100) := 'CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW v AS SELECT ';
  b CONSTANT VARCHAR2(100) := ' FROM TAB';
  c VARCHAR2(3000);
  i NUMBER;
  max_cols CONSTANT NUMBER := 10;
BEGIN
  SELECT listagg(column_name,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY column_id) INTO c
    FROM user_tab_columns
   WHERE table_name = 'TAB';  
  SELECT count(*) INTO i 
    FROM user_tab_columns
   WHERE table_name = 'TAB';  
  WHILE (i < max_cols) LOOP
    i := i + 1;
    c := c || ', ''dummy'' AS col_'||i;
  END LOOP;
  c := a || c || b;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(C);
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE c;
END;
/
```

The result is a view that selects all columns of table `tab` and fills up columns containing `dummy` until 10 columns are reached:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW v AS 
SELECT C1,C2,C3,C4,C5,C6,C7, 
       'dummy' AS col_8, 'dummy' AS col_9, 'dummy' AS col_10 
  FROM TAB;
```

Next idea is a [pipelined table function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14289/dcitblfns.htm) to fill up the columns of your table, but that violates again your no PL/SQL requirement.

Thirdly, [polymorphic table functions](https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclemagazine/how-to-dynamically-change-the-columns-in-a-sql-query) come to mind, but they are only available from Oracle 18.